# How can I fix this problem when trying to delete a folder and an alert with the message Error 0x80004005: Unspecified error appears?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install

[image]

I've this folder "node_modules" and I want to delete it but when I try to do so I got this error. I installed it using "npm install" command from the terminal. I cloned the project from github, installed node_modules (installation was just fine) and changed the branch. The problem happened because I deleted that node_modules by mistake and tried to reinstall it, installation didn't work fine this time so I decided to delete the folder and remake all the steps from the beginning.

Comment: If your app is running, enter ctl+c to kill and then try it.

Comment: Use https://lockhunter.com/ to see which program is using that resource